# Autofac TScanningActivatorData and WithMetadata

Tags: autofac

I am trying to do something like this. However the WithMetadata method wont let me.

Is this a problem in Autofac and should TScanningActivatorData in the WithMetadata overloads be changed to TActivatorData, or am i approaching this the wrong way?

```
builder.RegisterType(myType).As<IMyType().AsSelf().WithMetadata("somekey", delegate(Type t)
                {
                   //dosomething
                    return t;
                });
```

This gives me the error on the WithMetadata method: `The type 'Autofac.Builder.ConcreteReflectionActivatorData' cannot be used as type parameter 'TScanningActivatorData' in the generic type or method 'Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.WithMetadata<TLimit,TScanningActivatorData,TRegistrationStyle>(Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit,TScanningActivatorData,TRegistrationStyle>, string, System.Func<System.Type,object>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Autofac.Builder.ConcreteReflectionActivatorData' to 'Autofac.Features.Scanning.ScanningActivatorData'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a more suitable overload for what you're trying to achieve. The `t` parameter passed in to the delegate is the same as `myType` - so the equivalent code is:

```
var someValue = DoSomething(myType);
builder.RegisterType(myType)
    .As<IMyType>()
    .AsSelf()
    .WithMetadata("somekey", someValue);
```

The overload you've been looking at is for use with scanning registrations, e.g. when using `RegisterAssemblyTypes()` rather than `RegisterType()`.

Hope this helps.
Nick

Comment: This works thx!. You mentioned scanning registrations. Is it possible to scan a collection of Types instead of an Assembly? That would be even more perfect.

Comment: foreach (var t in myTypes) { builder.RegisterType(t)... } :)